# Soluble group algebras and centralizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $K$ be field with $\mathrm{char}(K) = p > 0$ and $G$ a finite group such that $KG$ is soluble. Then the $p$-Sylow-subgroup of $G$ is normal and contains the derived group of $G$ and let $H$ be an abelian $p'$-Hall-subgroup. The radical $J=\mathrm{rad}(KG)$ of $KG$ is $\mathrm{Aug}(KP)KG$ and $KH$ is a radicalcomplement.

I invenstigated the following: Take a subalgebra $T$ of $KH$ and determine $C_J(T)$ and afterwards $C_{KH}(C_J(T))$. Then $T$ is a subalgebra of $C_{KH}(C_J(T))$.

I could proove that starting this process again with $C_{KH}(C_J(T))$ then its stable. I also describe for $T=KU$ and $U$ a subgroup of $H$ the subalgebras $C_J(T)$ and $C_{KH}(C_J(T))$ using group operation. In particular its possible to answer when $KU$ is stable under this construction, when not and when it reaches $KH$ or $Z(KG)\cap KH$.

My question is whether there are any ideas for a general unital subalgebra of $KH$ (maybe under the restriction that $K$ is a splitting field of $KH$. In this case the subalegrbas are known by using the primitive othogonal idempotents in $KH$ (see [Scheja & Storch](http://www.amazon.com/G%C3%BCnter-Scheja/e/B004563BYW/)). They can be contructed by the orthogonal idempotents using partitions).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please correctly typeset your question. You are obviously a pure math major, and it is for your own benefit to learn some $\LaTeX$ ;-).

Comment: Hi Troy thanks for your comment. I am familiar but I do not know how to include latex here!?

Comment: I have edit the changes. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I have edited all my questions now. What do you mean by "missed several spot"?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it (may take time to take effet).

Comment: What is a "soluble group algebra"? I know what is a soluble group, and any group algebra is an additive abelian group and thus trivially soluble...

Comment: An associative algebra is called soluble if its abelian modulo its Jacobson Radical. Another description is that it possesses an descending series of ideals for which is factor is abelian.

Comment: I have asked this question on mathoverflow as well.

Comment: I think we can close the question.